# Pass to a Variable a query result of knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, knex.js

I'm trying to attribute the result of a select query with Knexjs to a variable.
My code is this:

```
function getAllCategories() {
let categories;
categories = database.from("categories").select("category").then(function (rows) {
    for (let row of rows) {
        console.log(row)
    }
    });
console.log(categories)
```

}

When i call the function:
.then write on terminal the array of objects like this:

```
{ category: 'Pasticceria' }
{ category: 'Salati' }
...
```

Instead if i console.log(categories); on terminal print this:

```
    Promise [Object] {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined
}
```

How can I attribute to a variable to be able to cycle it?
Many thanks to all for help, I have been banging my head for several days.

Comment: `categories` is a `Promise`, you can learn more about promises from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) you should also look into `async/await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getAllCategories returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is what you are seeing when you call the function. The easiest thing to do would be to wrap whatever code calls getAllCategories in an async function, then await the value of getAllCategories. I assume that you want getAllCategories to return the categories, so it might look something like this:

```js
async function wrapper() { 
  async function getAllCategories() {
    return database.from("categories").select("category")
  };
  const categories = await getAllCategories() 
  // do whatever you want to do with categories
 }
```

You can read about async/await syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

As Adam tropp mention the categories now return a promise that which need to be executed, When you call the .then() method it calls in the background the exec() method, Same as if you use async/await when you use await it return the result that supposed to be thrown in the then block.
That also gives you the benefit of chaining in your query

```
async function getAllCategories() {
  return database.from("categories").select("category")
};
const categories = await getAllCategories().where('id', '=', 1) 
  // do whatever you want to do with categories
```

The getAllCategories() Method Adam made return a promise that you can chain whatever you want to it, and it will only execute if you called .then() method or used the await which i kenda prefer.