# Is there a way to get a Promise to return a result before reaching the view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am developing a Node app on my home server to be a simple project tracker. I am pretty OK with javascript but have never written anything that encountered issues with asynchronous requests, until now. The concept of Promise is new to me and, although I have found several examples that all work in some way, I still can't get the expected output. Here is the scenario:

1. I login as admin
2. I click a List Projects button
3. Node routes this to the listProjects function
4. If admin then get a list of clients from database (knex)

Here's where things get unexpected.
I want to see

```
A
{client_id: 1, client_name: 'Robert'},{...}
B
{client_id: 1, client_name: 'Robert'},{...}
C
{client_id: 1, client_name: 'Robert'},{...}
```

Instead I get

```
B
{}
C
Promise {\<pending\>}
A
{client_id: 1, client_name: 'Robert'},{...}
```

The code below includes the example answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716394/pass-to-a-variable-a-query-result-of-knex)
When using db.then I get

```
B
{}
A
{client_id: 1, client_name: 'Robert'},{...}
C
{client_id: 1, client_name: 'Robert'},{...}
```

which was my original approach and much better than the example I found using async/await but it still means that the code might reach the render before the Promise of for clients has been fulfilled
I want the clientList to be avilable before reaching the res.render in every case. What am I doing wrong?

```
async function wrapper() {
    async function getClients() {
        return db(client_table)
    }
    const clients = await getClients()
    console.log('A')
    console.table(clients)
    return clients
}
var listProjects = function(req, res) {
    var clients
    let projects = {}
    let whereClause = {}
    if (loggedIn) {
        if (isAdmin) {
            // Get a list of clients
            /*db(client_table).then((rows) => {
                    clients = rows
                                console.log('A')
                                console.table(clients)
                })*/
            clients = wrapper()
            console.log('B')
            console.table(clients)
        } else {
            // add where clause to filter get only this user's projects
            whereClause['c.user_id'] = req.session.user_id
        }
        db(project_table).innerJoin(project2client.target, project2client.condition).innerJoin(user2client.target, user2client.condition).where(whereClause).then((rows) => {
            console.log('C')
            console.log(clients)
            res.render('project', {
                title: 'List of projects',
                clientList: clients,
                recordset: rows
            })
        })
    } else {
        res.render('project', {
            title: 'List of projects',
            messages: {
                warning: 'Login to see your projects'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Initially I had my code nested in db.then calls but that made too many nested functions (maybe right now that isn't a problem but as I add more database retrievals then could get messy)

Comment: You forgot to `await` the return value of `wrapper`.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I get an error when I do that because listProjects is not async so making that async as well as await did the trick.